# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i think my code was correct. but i got error undefined identifier.. i hope you can help me, im new on javascript.. thanks in advance..

```
$('#media-select').on('change',function(){
                var dt = $(this).val();
                alert(dt);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: 'media-select=' dt,
                    url: url,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#result-media-uploader').load(url);
                    }
                });
            });
```

thats the code,

Comment: I think either this line giving problem `data: 'media-select=' dt,` or `url` is not defined.\

Comment: Are you missing the + sign at data: 'media-select=' dt?

Comment: not even a line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing the concatenation is wrong,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: 'media-select=' + dt, //concatenation using +
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result-media-uploader').load(url);
    }
});
```

Use `+` symbol for performing a concatenation, otherwise compiler would throw an error like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

Create an object instead of using `'media-select=' + dt`.

```
var toPost={};
toPost['media-select']=dt;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: toPost, 
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result-media-uploader').load(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks.. (y) that is good reference